# Should a procedure from message queue activation set on a loop?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, service-broker

I'm trying to start using SQL Server Service Broker to audit asynchronous what the users of a intranet application are doing.

I've create the message, contract, queue and service. Set up a procedure to fire on activation of this queue.

So far, so good. Messages are being sent and received.

The procedure receives the Top 1 message from that queue and does what it need to do (basically an insert into a table) and exits.

**My question:** does the procedure that receives the message need to be on infinite loop? The `MAX_QUEUE_READERS` setting of the Queue is 2. Does that mean that always will be 2 instances of the procedure running, regardless of the number of messages in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is better to have a loop in your activation procedure. Simply put, Service Broker only calls your activation procedure when a new message arrives in the queue. However, if procedures are already running, and the MAX_QUEUE_READERS pool is exhausted, it can't spawn any additional processing threads.

As such, if your queue is populated faster than your procedure completes its work, you will start to see unprocessed messages begin accumulating in the queue.

Another thing is, calling a procedure incurs an additional cost, however small. If you will try to mitigate the issue by increasing the MAX_QUEUE_READERS value, eventually you might start to notice this overhead. That, and it still doesn't guarantee that all messages will be processed, and none of them will be forgotten.

Below is a typical skeleton structure for such a procedure, you should follow this approach if you are to build a reliable, resilient system:

```
create procedure [dbo].[ssb_QProcessor_MyQueue]
with execute as owner as

set nocount, ansi_nulls, ansi_padding, ansi_warnings, concat_null_yields_null, quoted_identifier, arithabort on;
set numeric_roundabort, xact_abort, implicit_transactions off;

declare @Handle uniqueidentifier, @MessageType sysname, @Body xml;
declare @Error int, @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048), @ProcId int = @@procid;


-- Fast entry check for queue contents
if not exists (select 0 from dbo.MySBQueueName with (nolock))
    return;

while exists (select 0 from sys.service_queues where name = 'MySBQueueName' and is_receive_enabled = 1) begin

    begin try
    begin tran;

    -- Receive something, if any
    waitfor (
        receive top (1) @Handle = conversation_handle,
            @MessageType = message_type_name,
            @Body = message_body
        from dbo.MySBQueueName
    ), timeout 3000;

    if @Handle is null begin
        -- Empty, get out
        rollback;
        break;
    end;

    -- Whatever processing logic you have should be put here



    commit;
    end try
    begin catch

    if nullif(@Error, 0) is null
        select @Error = error_number(), @ErrorMessage = error_message();

    -- Check commitability of the transaction
    if xact_state() = -1
        rollback;
    else if xact_state() = 1
        commit;

    -- Try to resend the message again (up to you)
    exec dbo.[ssb_Poison_Retry] @MessageType = @MessageType, @MessageBody = @Body,
        @ProcId = @ProcId, @ErrorNumber = @Error, @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage;

    end catch;

    -- Reset dialog handle
    select @Handle = null, @Error = null, @ErrorMessage = null;

end;

-- Done!
return;
```

Comment: Do you always receive a message inside a transaction? Are there cases where using a transaction is detrimental?

Comment: @Elathan, you are asking a wrong question :). When you `receive` message(s) from the queue while inside a transaction and that transaction gets rolled back later for any reason, the message(s) in question go back to the queue. If you retrieve them without a transaction and your processing code fails to deliver, they are lost. Keep in mind that some errors may result in batch termination, so you won't be able to reach the `catch` block to log anything anywhere. So, if you don't care about your data, sure - ditch the transaction and go ahead, it might give you some minuscule speed-up.